# SMTP/POP3 through proxy System.getProperties() vs new Properties()?

Tags: java, proxy, smtp, jakarta-mail, pop3

Im trying to get mail from a POP3 server through a proxy. Most "tutorials" suggest doing something like

```
 Properties p = System.getProperties();
 p.setProperty("proxySet", "true");//does this line even do anything?
 p.setProperty("socksProxyHost", proxyHost);
 p.setPorperty("socksProxyPort", proxyPort);
 p.setProperty("socksProxyVersion", "5");//or 4 if you want to use 4
 p.setProperty("mail.pop3.socketFactory.class", SSL_FACTORY);
 p.setProperty("mail.pop3.socketFactory.fallback", "false");//also not sure what it does
 p.setProperty("mail.pop3.port", portOnHostYouWantToTalkTo);
 p.setProperty("mail.pop3.socketFactory.port", portOnHostYouWantToTalkTo);

 Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(p, null);
 //or session = Session.getInstance(p, null);

 URLName urlName = new URLName(protocol, hostYouwantToTalkTo, portOnHostYouWantToTalkTo, null, mailbox, mailboxPassword);
 Store store = session.getStore(urlName);
```

Now, if I do something like this I get an exception:

```
java.net.SocketException: Can't connect to SOCKS proxy:Connection timed out: connect.
```

My POP3 server does not log any connections, suggesting there is a proxy issue or an error in my code. I am using 73.29.157.190:29099 for now.

2) If, however, I do

```
 Properties p = new Properties();
 //all the same logic and stuff
 Session = Session.getInstance(p, null);
```

My POP3 server logs a connection from localhost, and works properly, suggesting that I am NOT using a proxy to connect to it and everything else is fine.

My question is, why do "tutorials" use System.getProperties() and pass it to getInstance()? Every Session instance will keep a reference to System.properties. So, effectively every Session instance will be affected every time you try to create a new one or alter System.getProperties() in any way so you might as well reuse the same one.

Does javamail need something set in System.properties specifically and not the ones passed to Session?

Also, what parameters do you need to set in order to get javamail to use a proxy? What does System.properties have that makes it work unlike my new Properties? A link to a good tutorial or documentation that explains it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First, [get rid of all the socket factory stuff](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes), you don't need it.

Next, make sure you really have a SOCKS proxy and not just a web proxy.  If you do, see [this JavaMail FAQ entry](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#proxy).

Setting the System properties for a SOCKS proxy will cause **all** network connections from your program to go through the proxy server, which may not be what you want.

Comment: Thanks. The real question is what needs to be set in properties to make java mail try to retrieve (or send) through a proxy?

Comment: Did you read the FAQ entry?  Are you sure you have a SOCKS proxy?

Comment: No, I am not sure. That is however irrelevant at this time. The more important problem at this time is why setting mail.pop3.socks.port and mail.pop3.socks.host has no effect. I have proper versions of JVM and java mail. There is no http proxy set anywhere else. I am simply out of ideas at this point why the POP3 server simply accepts a connection as if there is no proxy and works otherwise the same.

Comment: Fix your use of [Session.getDefaultInstance](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).  If that doesn't help, update your post with the settings you're currently using and the [JavaMail debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug).

Comment: It was actually a Maven automagic issue this entire time. It refused to download the version of java mail jar I asked for even after clearing repo. But thats another thing to try to fix.